# Coupon collector problem

Tags: probability, expectation, coupon-collector

> Let $T$ be the time to collect all $n$ coupons, and let $t_{i}$ be the time to collect the i-th coupon after $i − 1$ coupons have been collected. Think of $T$ and $t_{i}$ as random variables. Observe that the probability of collecting a new coupon given $i − 1$ coupons is $p_{i} = \frac{n − (i − 1)}{n}$. Therefore, $t_{i}$ has geometric distribution with expectation $\frac{1}{p_{i}}$. By the linearity of expectations we have:

That's an except from wikipedia page. I understand $p_{i} = \frac{n-(i-1)}{n}$. But I don't quite understand why $t_{i}$ is $\frac{1}{p_{i}}$. I appreciate much if anyone can explain it.

Thanks

Comment: It is a standard fact about a geometrically distributed random variable $X$ with parameter $p$ that $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$. It has also been proved repeatedly on MSE.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer to allow this question to be closed as answered:

As André has pointed out, this is a well-known fact; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants).